# Understanding any keyword in Python if statements

Tags: python, for-loop, any

I have 2 Python list which are as follows:

```
>>> clean = ['SNAT2VIP', 'http2https']
>>> ugly = ['/Common/SNAT2VIP', '/Common/http2https']
```

I now need to iterate through each member of clean and see if it exists anywhere in ugly. By 'exists', I mean that it could be present as a whole or as a `substring` in an element of ugly.

This is what I came up with:

```
>>> for item in clean:
...     if (word in item for word in ugly):
...         print "yes"
...     else:
...         print "no"
...
yes
yes
```

Works as I expect.However,if I add `any`,the output changes as follows:

```
>>> for item in clean:
...     if any(word in item for word in ugly):
...         print "yes"
...     else:
...         print "no"
...
no
no
```

What does `any` do to change the output ?

Comment: it means "If any of the word (iterating over ugly) exists inside item THEN print yes, else print no"

Comment: In your first `if`, you create a generator. You never evaluate that generator, but a generator always is "truthy" when interpreted as a boolean, so it's always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `Boolean` value of your expression `(word in item for word in ugly)` will always be `True` as it returns a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) object.

You can check using [bool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool) built-in function.

```
bool(word in item for word in ugly)
```

So to work with [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) built-in function you have to follow:-

```
if any(item in word for word in ugly):
```

Instead of:-

```
if any(word in item for word in ugly):
```

As your `word` string resides in `item` string.

```
>>> 'SNAT2VIP' in '/Common/SNAT2VIP'
True
>>> 
>>> '/Common/SNAT2VIP' in 'SNAT2VIP'
False
```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the wrong way around

```
if any(word in item for word in ugly):
```

This checks if all words in `ugly` are present in *every item* in`clean` as well. You want to check the other way around. Change to

```
for word in clean:
    if any(word in item for item in ugly):
        print "yes"
```

Comment: This only checks whether the word is in the list, not whether its contained in one of the words _in_ that list.

Answer (score 2):

Your first bit of code if buggy. Generators always have a truth value of `True` -- regardless of the items that the generator may produce or even if the generator will produce no items. eg.

```
>>> print("false values generator: {}".format(bool(False for item in [1])))
false values generator: True
>>> print("empty values generator truth value: {}".format(bool(True for item in [])))
empty values generator truth value: True
```

As such your code will always enter the True branch of the if statement.

You also had your arguments the wrong way around. You were checking if the "ugly" word was in the "clean" word. This would have been more apparent if you'd chosen clearer names for your variables. The following will work as expected:

```
for clean_word in clean:
    if any(clean_word in ugly_word for ugly_word in ugly):
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

Comment: @Dunes..i understood the bit about generators always returning True regardless of the values in them..however,what i did not understand is that with any used with the generator,why do i get a no..

Comment: The `any` function returned `False` because all the  values returned by the generator were `False`. This is because you were asking if the ugly words were in the clean words, rather than if the clean words were in the ugly words. This is why I mentioned trying to chose better variable names in future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `comprehension`

```
>>>any(j for i in clean for j in ugly if i in j)
True
```